# Dropping the rows by checking whether it has multiple values in R

Tags: r, filter

I have a data frame in this form;

```
Year  Department  Jan      Feb ................... Dec
2017  TF           15.15   225.51  ..............  5562.1
2015  CIF        ...................................  
2013  TTR       ....................................
2011  COR      ....................
.    .............................
.     ......................
```

As a summary, I want to create an algorithm but first I have to make this filtering:

- If a department does not have a value for 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016 years, than I want to exclude that department from my data set.
- In other words, by reading the each departments data, filtering the data by departments that has all four years values in the months columns.

I tried exists, is.na but the multiple filtering always fails. And another handicap is that filter works for only single condition, but here I need like 4 condition. 4 years values must be exist to use them in next step.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a clear duplicate to this question. Seems like a quick fix with `group_by`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(Year = c(2013:2016, 2015, 2016),
           Department = c(rep('TF', 4), 'CIF', 'TTR'))

df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>    Year Department
#>   <dbl>      <chr>
#> 1  2013         TF
#> 2  2014         TF
#> 3  2015         TF
#> 4  2016         TF
#> 5  2015        CIF
#> 6  2016        TTR

df %>%
  group_by(Department) %>%
  mutate(x = Year %in% c(2013:2016),
         y = sum(x)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(y == 4)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>    Year Department     x     y
#>   <dbl>      <chr> <lgl> <int>
#> 1  2013         TF  TRUE     4
#> 2  2014         TF  TRUE     4
#> 3  2015         TF  TRUE     4
#> 4  2016         TF  TRUE     4
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using R base:

```
df = read.table(text = "Year, Department
2016,TF
2017,TF
2013,CIF
2014,CIF
2015,CIF
2016,CIF
2013,TTR", header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df[df$Department %in% subset(aggregate(subset(df, Year %in% c(2013,2014,2015,2016)), by=list(n$Department), FUN=length), Department==4)[,1], ]
```

Output:

```
  Year Department
3 2013        CIF
4 2014        CIF
5 2015        CIF
6 2016        CIF
```